# Font rendering wrong only on Windows Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have an google served Open Sans font on my site and only on WIn Chrome something is behaving strangly... font is thick and ugly.
I have tried Win FF and Safari... OK. Mac Chrome, FF and Safari also ok.

What I was able to find is that something is generating this before my closing head tag:

*{font-family:undefined,sans-serif!important;}

http://marinmartinovic.com/MK_test

Any pointer would be highly appreciated!

thx

Comment: I tracked down an issue. Some js script is adding this class to head tag... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

an alternative solution, if you are willing to store fonts which you are using locally, find ttf or otf files for that font and store locally in the same directory as your css file. Then declare the font using @font-face{ fontName:url();} in your css and then start using them.